# Uncaught reference error with Prestashop Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

[image]

The error apears when i click the blue "add row" button". Any help trying to troubleshoot the problem?

Jquery is loaded before the tool and the script is run after the page is loaded

error occurs in line 9 of this code:

```
if($.isEmptyObject(num)) // check if any row already exist if not set 1
    num = 1;
else // check if any row already exist if yes set max + 1
    num = Math.max.apply(Math,num) + 1;

html += '<div id="megamenu-row-'+num+'" class="megamenu-row row">';
    html += '<div class="clearfix">';
        html += '<div class="add-column-button-container col-lg-6">';
            html += '<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="btn btn-success add-megamenu-col">'+add_megamenu_column+'</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '<div class="remove-row-button col-lg-6 text-right">';
            html += '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-row" href="#" onclick="return false;">'+btn_remove_row_text+'</a>';
        html += '</div">';
    html += '</div>';
    html += '<input type="hidden" name="row_content" />';
html += '</div>';

return html;
```

}

Comment: We can't help you with this little informations. As it is this question should be closed. Please add some code.

Comment: i added the code where the issue happens

Comment: the add_megamenu_column variable is not defined you shood declare it,

Answer (score 0):

You might imported some products/categories with wrong `\r` or `\n` in their names and this brokes up back.js. Replace in */modules/tmmegamenu/views/templates/admin/additem.tpl* on *line 223*

```
{addJsDef option_list=$option_select}
```

on

`{addJsDef option_list=$option_select|replace:"\r":""|replace:"\n":""}`

This should works.